# How to access HTML object constructed below using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to limit a selection in my list - string check boxes.
However, I can't seem to select the object in HTML. I am using an application builder with my objects and trying to implement an additional JavaScript code.

I have tried using the document.getElementsByClassName(), .querySelector() and .getElementsByTag() to select my objects but no success.

I can't figure out as to why this code won't work. Could it be because I am wasn't able to construct my code correctly or use the selectors properly?
I am not really familiar with JavaScript, any help or directions would be very appreciated.

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
var max = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
  checks[i].onclick = selectiveCheck;

function selectiveCheck(event) {
  var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll(".item:checked");
  if (checkedChecks.length >= max + 1)
    return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="MultiSelectBox" class="ListData SelectBox cbFormSelect" style="z- 
index: 1002; left: 109px; top: 43px; width: 107px; height: 151px; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <div class="Body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">

      <div style="">
        <div class="Item" style="outline: none;">
          <input type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin- 
right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_0"><label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_0">Apple</label></div>

        <div class="Item" style="outline: none;"><input type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_1"><label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_1">Banana</label></div>

        <div class="Item" style="outline: none;"><input type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_2"><label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_2">Melon</label></div>

        <div class="Item" style="outline: none;"><input type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_3"><label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_3">Mango</label></div>

        <div class="Item" style="outline: none;"><input type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_4"><label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_4">Grapes</label></div>

        <div class="Item" style="outline: none;"><input type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_5"><label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_5">Peach</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected result is quite simple, the script shouldn't not allow all users to select more than 2 options.

Comment: The `class` of elements is set to `"Item"` at HTML though selector used at JavaScript is `".item"`. Selectors strings are case sensitive. There are no elements having `class` set to `"item"` at HTML.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for pointing that out, I forgot to mention that I have tried both cases but didn't work too.

Comment: What do you mean by _"didn't work"_? The code in `selectiveCheck` only  evaluaties the `.length` of `checkedChecks`, correct? What is the expected result?

Comment: As I understand, the function is limiting the user to select up to 2 options only. as I checked there is no validation still. did I get it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it completely wrong. You are checking ".item:checked", so **it's the checkbox who should have the class "item", not the div**.

```
<div style="">
        <div style="outline: none;">
            <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_0">
            <label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_0">Apple</label>
        </div>
        <div  style="outline: none;">
        <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_1">
        <label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_1">Banana</label>
        </div>
        <div style="outline: none;">
        <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_2">
        <label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_2">Melon</label>
        </div>
        <div style="outline: none;">
        <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_3">
        <label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_3">Mango</label>
        </div>
        <div style="outline: none;">
        <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_4">
        <label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_4">Grapes</label>
        </div>
        <div style="outline: none;">
        <input class="item" type="checkbox" style="outline: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 6px;" id="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_5">
        <label for="InsertRecordCheckList_3a4dfdb26cc834_checked_5">Peach</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Rest is Ok

Comment: Hi, I suspect the same thing, however as I am using an application builder, I have no ability to assign class or modify the objects from the backend. The HTML is pre-defined. Perhaps you have an idea for a work around on this? thanks!

Comment: Then access through child selector like this -

`var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".item>input[type='checkbox']");
   var max = 2;
   for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
     checks[i].onclick = selectiveCheck;

   function selectiveCheck(event) {
     var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll(".item>input[type='checkbox']:checked");
     if (checkedChecks.length >= max + 1)
    return false;
   }`